# Python string concatenation for JSON payload

Tags: python, json, string-concatenation

I'm trying to modify this piece of code generated by Postman to replace hard-coded strings with string variables but I keep getting

`KeyError: '\n\t"username"'`

Here's the code

```
username = "jose"
email = "some_email"
password = "1234"

url = "some_url"

payload = '{\n\t\"username\": {},\n\t\"email\": {},\n\t\"password\": {}\n}'.format(username, email, password)
headers = {
  'Content-Type': 'application/json'
}

response = requests.request("POST", url, headers=headers, data=payload)

print(response.text.encode('utf8'))
```

Comment: You have not properly escaped the actual curly braces in the code. You would have to double them. To avoid such problems don't use sting formatting to construct JSON. Create a dictionary and use `json.dumps()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can properly form your json this way:

```
import json
username = "jose"
email = "some_email"
password = "1234"

url = "some_url"

payload = json.dumps({"username": username, "email":email, "password":password}, indent=4)
headers = { 'Content-Type': 'application/json'}

response = requests.request("POST", url, headers=headers, data=payload)

print(response.text.encode('utf8'))
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at example here: https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/user/quickstart/

```
>>> r = requests.post('https://httpbin.org/post', data = {'key':'value'})
```

You could just use dicitonary for the data.